# How to exploit default mysql value column?

Tags: vb.net

I've a bit problem, I valorize a variable in this way:

```
 Dim hash As String = ""

 If hashes.SelectedValue IsNot Nothing Then

    hash = hashes.SelectedValue

 End If
```

my table structure:

```
  `resources_guid` char(36) DEFAULT '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
```

when I perform the insert with MySqlCommand and the variable is empty, I get "NULL" instead of the default value, I tried also to set only `Dim hash As String` but the default value isn't exploited. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading between the lines, you're generated an insert command, passing `hash` as the value to set for your `resources_guid` column?

If you supply *any* value, even null, that will be used instead of the default.  To use the default, you need to not supply that parameter/column to the `MySqlCommand` object *at all*.

Comment: Yes in this column I perform the insert passing this parameter: MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@resources_guidp", hash); now if hash is NULL so not valorized the DEFAULT value should be exploited.

Comment: But `NULL` is a valid value, so it will get used.  The only way to get the DB engine to use its default is to not supply a value at all.